# How to use github api to retrieve artifacts for specific commit sha?

Tags: github-api, github-cli

I am trying to build a query that would retrieve github artifacts for a given commit share for which I do know that there are runs with artifacts.

I was already able to retrieve the workflow run id using the sha using something like:

```
gh run list -b main -w ci \
  --json headSha,conclusion,databaseId \
  --jq ".[] | select(.headSha == \"21e6188608352ac2ed8e2d4c65e11ae2dbe20291\" and .conclusion == \"success\") \
  | .databaseId" \
  | jq  --color-output
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/artifacts \
  --jq ".artifacts[] | select(.workflow_run.head_sha == \"21e6188608352ac2ed8e2d4c65e11ae2dbe20291\")"
```

This should retrieve them for specific commit but you can also add `and .workflow_run.id == 123` to filter by run id.